# Getting several count with different filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, criteria

I am rather new to JPA 2 and it's Criteria Builder.
I would like to create a query where I do several count with different filter each.

It will be like this in postgreSQL

```
select  id,
        count(created_at) filter(where status_log = 'hold') as holding,
        count(created_at) filter(where status_log = 'resume') as resume
from log
where status_log in ('hold', 'resume')
group by id
```

it's a success in postgreSQL, where the result is as follows
[result of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeasC.png)

My desired result when using criteria builder is as follows

```
[
   [
    some_id_1, 
    1, //count of hold
    2  //count of resume
   ],
   [
    some_id_2, 
    1, 
    1
   ],
...
]
```

How can I achieve this result using criteria?

Thanks in Advance!